What happens with Github token which never expire but user no longer exists?
I wanted to know can I still use a token and user, even if user doesn't exists. As token has no expiration date.
Use case is that I want to use a user and it's personal access token (with no expiration date) in CI pipeline to push docker images to Github Packages(ghcr). Will that token still be valid forever?
Note: Can't use service account
